# Student in Paralegal Studies working for a pro se legal in NC?

Tags: unlicensed-practice, prison

Student in Paralegal Studies as of 10/23/2023. Could I send legal information, documentation, case laws to someone that is Pro Se in prison?

Comment: Are you a lawyer? Maybe you have an answer.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Realistically, while the details would matter a little, this would probably be unauthorized practice of law and would be illegal. You could probably provide general textbooks to someone, but information tailored to their circumstances would not be permissible.

Comment: getting found out could even bar the student from passing the character-fitness test of the bar exam...